# how to pass array from variable group to ARM template in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am working on creating cosmos db databases. I need to pass the dbname and throughput from the vaiable group. I made my template working using thecopy function. now I am integrating it to the pipeline, but when I pass

```
[{"name": "DB1","throughput": 400 },{"name":"DB2", "throughput": 400 }]
```

its coming as

```
[{\"name\": \"DB1\",\"throughput\": 400 },{\"name\":\"DB2\", \"throughput\": 400 }]
```

right now I am using Azure cli task to replace \" with ", so it will become an array again. but is there a better way to pass the array from variable group to arm template parameters json file?

Comment: Could you please show more details? I have tried but unable to reproduce your issue. Can you show how you set and how you use the variable?

Comment: I think it was a spacing issue where in the variable group it was inserted with space and then while retrieving its coming with the extra slash, without the space it works fine - This is how I put it in variable group where I got the slash[ 
  {     "name"   :     "DB1",      "throughput"   :     400     }]